# django query question

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Assume I have such simple model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    b_date = models.DateField()
```

Now assume that my query result from `Foo.objects.all()` , I retrieve something like this:

```
[
    {'name': 'zed', 'b_date': '2009-12-23'},
    {'name': 'amy', 'b_date': '2009-12-6'},
    {'name': 'joe', 'b_date': '2009-12-26'},
    {'name': 'wayne', 'b_date': '2009-12-14'},
    {'name': 'chris', 'b_date': '2009-12-9'},
]
```

Now I need to get the earliest date from b_date (which is '2009-12-6' for our case and the latest one ('2009-12-23' for the example) and generate a list that start from the begining and iterates through the end such as:

```
what_I_want = ['2009-12-6','2009-12-7','2009-12-8' .............. '2009-12-22','2009-12-23']
```

How would you solve this, in the most efficient way. doing this either in view or templete would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Foo.objects.order_by('b_date').values_list('b_date', flat=True)
```